# VPS imap-login error

Tags: email, vps, dovecot

please, could you help me with my problem? I installed VPS. Everythings ok, except email and I cannot figure, why it doesn't work as expected - Squirell mail returns when trying to log in:

> ERROR: Connection dropped by IMAP server.

Do you know, where might be problem? I'm newbie in this and I'm not really sure, what should I do with this?

Here is my error log file for mail.

```
Aug  8 13:48:33 vps191267 dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Too many invalid commands (no auth attempts in 57 secs): user=<>, rip=188.175.155.118, lip=5.135.147.5, session=<kU3/VMsczAC8r5t2> 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: auth-worker(16650): mysql(localhost): Connected to database dbispconfig 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: auth: Error: BUG: Authentication client sent unknown handshake command: REQUEST?2492858369?16648?1?267a629bebc2e583c3dd1c16f0bbe4d6 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: pop3: Error: Authentication server didn't send valid SPID as expected: MECH  PLAIN   plaintext 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: pop3: Error: Disconnected from auth server, aborting (client-pid=16648 client-id=1) 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: pop3-login: Internal login failure (pid=16648 id=1) (internal failure, 1 succesful auths): user=<kozusnik@inovestudio.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=188.175.155.118, lip=5.135.147.5, mpid=16651, TLS, session=<X6AcVsscFgC8r5t2> 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: auth: Warning: auth client 16648 disconnected with 1 pending requests: EOF 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: auth: Error: BUG: Authentication client sent unknown handshake command: REQUEST?3822977025?16652?1?b44d33a06c31a87042d6fd62ead367eb 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: pop3: Error: Authentication server didn't send valid SPID as expected: MECH  PLAIN   plaintext 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: pop3: Error: Disconnected from auth server, aborting (client-pid=16652 client-id=1) 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: pop3-login: Internal login failure (pid=16652 id=1) (internal failure, 1 succesful auths): user=<kozusnik@inovestudio.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=188.175.155.118, lip=5.135.147.5, mpid=16653, TLS, session=<jiYiVsscFwC8r5t2> 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: auth: Warning: auth client 16652 disconnected with 1 pending requests: EOF 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: auth: Error: BUG: Authentication client sent unknown handshake command: REQUEST?3522297857?16654?1?c451433874707f84a4507c06f1baa0b0 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: pop3: Error: Authentication server didn't send valid SPID as expected: MECH  PLAIN   plaintext 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: pop3: Error: Disconnected from auth server, aborting (client-pid=16654 client-id=1) 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: pop3-login: Internal login failure (pid=16654 id=1) (internal failure, 1 succesful auths): user=<kozusnik@inovestudio.com>, method=LOGIN, rip=188.175.155.118, lip=5.135.147.5, mpid=16655, TLS, session=<mWknVsscGAC8r5t2> 
Aug  8 13:48:52 vps191267 dovecot: auth: Warning: auth client 16654 disconnected with 1 pending requests: EOF 
Aug  8 13:48:53 vps191267 dovecot: auth: Error: BUG: Authentication client sent unknown handshake command: REQUEST?688128001?16656?1?7cdc3d5f20c3a059dd83f3536b8741a3 
Aug  8 13:48:53 vps191267 dovecot: pop3: Error: Authentication server didn't send valid SPID as expected: MECH  PLAIN   plaintext 
Aug  8 13:48:53 vps191267 dovecot: pop3: Error: Disconnected from auth server, aborting (client-pid=16656 client-id=1) 
Aug  8 13:48:53 vps191267 dovecot: pop3-login: Internal login failure (pid=16656 id=1) (internal failure, 1 succesful auths): user=<kozusnik@inovestudio.com>, method=LOGIN, rip=188.175.155.118, lip=5.135.147.5, mpid=16658, TLS, session=<xnssVsscGQC8r5t2> 
Aug  8 13:48:53 vps191267 dovecot: auth: Warning: auth client 16656 disconnected with 1 pending requests: EOF 
Aug  8 13:48:53 vps191267 dovecot: auth: Error: BUG: Authentication client sent unknown handshake command: REQUEST?2325348353?16659?1?867f8b63203996bc42ef07ce4b9e07b3 
Aug  8 13:48:53 vps191267 dovecot: pop3: Error: Authentication server didn't send valid SPID as expected: MECH  PLAIN   plaintext 
Aug  8 13:48:53 vps191267 dovecot: pop3: Error: Disconnected from auth server, aborting (client-pid=16659 client-id=1) 
Aug  8 13:48:53 vps191267 dovecot: pop3-login: Internal login failure (pid=16659 id=1) (internal failure, 1 succesful auths): user=<kozusnik@inovestudio.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=188.175.155.118, lip=5.135.147.5, mpid=16660, TLS, session=<toQ1VsscGgC8r5t2> 
Aug  8 13:48:53 vps191267 dovecot: auth: Warning: auth client 16659 disconnected with 1 pending requests: EOF
```

doveconf -n

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login

disable_plaintext_auth = no

listen = *,[::]

log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "

mail_privileged_group = vmail

passdb {

  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf

  driver = sql

}

plugin {

  quota = dict:user::file:/var/vmail/%d/%n/.quotausage

  sieve = /var/vmail/%d/%n/.sieve

}

protocols = imap pop3

service auth {

  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {

    group = postfix

    mode = 0660

    user = postfix

  }

  unix_listener auth-userdb {

    group = vmail

    mode = 0600

    user = vmail

  }

  user = root

}

service imap-login {

  client_limit = 1000

  process_limit = 500

}

ssl_cert = </etc/postfix/smtpd.cert

ssl_key = </etc/postfix/smtpd.key

ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3

userdb {

  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf

  driver = sql

}

protocol imap {

  mail_plugins = quota imap_quota

}

protocol pop3 {

  mail_plugins = quota

  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv

}

protocol lda {

  mail_plugins = sieve quota

}
```

Comment: At the moment, the issue looks like your IMAP server (dovecot) has been configured to authenticate from a MySQL database, and it's not working.

Comment: @MadHatter And do you have please any solution, how to repair it please?

Comment: We don't give walk-through fixes here, we give pointers.  To give any further pointers, we'll need to see your dovecot config - try editing it into your question.  I should add that I wouldn't have dovecot authenticate that way in a month of Sundays, so I may not be much more help (sorry).

Comment: I put doceconf -n output into my question.

Comment: No problem @MadHatter you are problably the only one who gave me any response...

Comment: No worries.  Take a look in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf`.  Does it make sense?  Does it point to any further files, and if so, do they also make sense?  Can you access the SQL db so configured using the configured credentials?  Can you get mysql to log queries so you can see exactly what's being asked?  How did you populate the contents of the queried DB?  Do the contents seem to match the queries being run?  These are the sort of questions you should be asking next.

Comment: Sorry for 2 days, without response, I became ill... I tried to update dovecot and now it works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear you're better.  You should write up an answer saying how you fixed it and. when the site lets you, accept this answer, so the question doesn't float around forever.

Comment: Yeah, I will do. Thank you @MadHatter Have a nice day!

Comment: restarting dovecot worked for me. someday I'd like to solve this once and for all.